# Using a Flex Library (RPC) in an ActionScript / Flash project?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a Flash application right now that is so far built entirely using ActionScript 3 (in Flash Builder) and (a little bit) in Flash Professional.

I need to use Web Services to handle certain things in the application, but there is no AS3 library for Web Services.  There is, however, a Flex library for handling Web Services requests (mx.rpc.soap.mxml.WebService).

I'd like to know if it's possible to import this library into my AS3 code and use it in my Flash project.  My project is not a Flex project, and I'm trying to avoid using Flex because I'm developing for the iPhone (using [Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/)), and Flex is (generally) too resource intensive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the classes available to you in the `flash.net` class path. These include LocalConnection, NetConnection, NetStream, SharedObject, Socket, XMLSocket, URLRequest, URLStream, and many others.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  So is the short answer as to whether or not I can use Flex libraries in a Flash project "no"?  It'd be a bit easier than constructing my own Web Services class.